# Why I keep authenticated in the server side after logged out on client side with ng-token-auth and devise-token-auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, authentication, devise

I'm using rails to create an API that is consumed by angularjs.
I'm using the gems **devise**, [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) and the angularjs module [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) to manage the sessions of my application. I have my app with default configuration.

I have two problems with this modules.

First, when I log in with a real account, I get logged in the front end and see the home page as is supposed to, but when I load an api Url that needs authentication I get 404 Unauthorized Error unless I refresh a couple times the home page (where i just logged in).

My second problem, that I believe is related, is that when I'm logged in both server side and client side, and then I sign out on client side I don't get signed out server side. I tested it by loading the same Api Url that needs authentication and before and after I sign out I still receive the json data and the current_user variable still contains the logged user.

This are my controllers for /login and /logout.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'templates', 'ng-token-auth']);
app.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $auth, $state) {
    $scope.login = {};

    $scope.submitLoginForm = function(loginCredentials) {
        $auth.submitLogin(loginCredentials).then(function(resp) {
            //console.log('logged in successfully');
            $state.go('loginRequired.index');
        }).catch(function(resp) {
            // handle error response
        });
    };
});
app.controller('LogoutController', function($scope, $auth, $state, $http) {
    $auth.signOut().then(function() {
        //console.log("User logged out");
        $state.go('login');
    }).catch(function() {
        alert("Error");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused because you have more than one devise scope. What do you have in your config/routes.rb file for mounting devise? devise_for, devise_scope, mount_devise_token_auth_for, etc

If you add a Warden callback inside, file: config/initializers/devise.rb
example:

```
Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user,auth,opts|
  # opts[:scope] could be :user, :api_user, etc
end
```

You will see different user scopes.